# Post data into controller with out using HTML Form in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

```
    public ActionResult Connect()
            {           
                    return View("Index");        
            }

    [HttpPost]
            public JsonResult Connect(string value)
            {
             ...
             return Json(new { success = true, message = "Success" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
             }
```

I have a `Controller` like above. I must create a `HTML` form in View (`Connect.cshtml`) to post and get result `return Json(...)`.

How can I post and result `return Json(...)` with out create `HTML` form.

I mean user can type from web browser: `Localhost:port/Controller/Connect/value`

Comment: I think you're looking for a GET request. If you want the user to be able to type it into the browser URL, I mean. Otherwise, you can send a POST request programmatically through JavaScript or something.

Comment: @Ellis I am currently creating a form for users to post and show result. But now I want user can post and get result by type it into the browser URL.

Comment: You can't just send a post request in the address bar. You can however, send a GET, with arguments.

Answer (score 0):

An illustration of what I mean in my comments:

Let's say you have a form. And that form is using HTTP POST to post to a location like http://localhost:5000/connect. What you can do in your code is have a method to accept arguments from a GET request to the same URL.

Something like:

```
// This is the method that takes POSTs from your form...
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Connect([FromBody]string value)
{
    // Do stuff with value...
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Connect([FromQuery]string value)
{
    // Your code here, do something with value...
}
```

Which you could then pass a value through the URL like http://localhost:5000/connect?value=something.

I should add that you do not want to send credentials through the URL. That's a very bad idea.